# Creating valuepair arrays SPServices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, spservices

I have the information below working, however if I have more than 3 value pairs it can be a long string. How do I turn the value pairs into an array? I tried to use this example but I'm not clear on how to add it. [valuepairs](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/550388)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>List Item to be added</strong></td>
<td><input id="Test1" name="Test1" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="Test2" name="Test2" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="Test3" name="Test3" type="text" /></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input name="ADD" id="btnAdd" type="submit" value="Add Item to List" /></td></tr>
</table>
<script src="jquery 1.11.1 stored in my library"></script>
<script src="SPServices SPServices 2014.01 stored in my library"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
                var IN1 = $("#Test1").val();
                var IN2 = $("#Test2").val();
                var IN3 = $("#Test3").val();

                AddListItem(IN1, IN2, IN3);
            });

        });

        function AddListItem(TitleField, FNField, LNField) {
            $().SPServices({
                operation: "UpdateListItems",
                async: false,
                batchCmd: "New",
                listName: "testlist",
                valuepairs: [["Title", TitleField], ["FirstName", FNField], ["LastName", LNField]],
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    alert("Data Saved! and Please check your List");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var MyvaluePairs = [];

    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        var IN1 = $("#Test1").val();
        var IN2 = $("#Test2").val();
        var IN3 = $("#Test3").val();

        MyvaluePairs.push(["Title", IN1]); 
        MyvaluePairs.push(["FirstName", IN2]); 
        MyvaluePairs.push(["LastName", IN3]); 
        MyvaluePairs.push(["Other", IN4]); 

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            batchCmd: "New",
            listName: "testlist",
            valuepairs: MyvaluePairs,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                alert("Data Saved! and Please check your List");
            }
        });

    });

});
```